# How do I add a value to a table?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

( Visual Studio 2010 | Win7 Ultimate | C# )

How do I add a value to a table?
I have a table called "suggestions" and I'm not sure how to add a value to it, remotely, not hardcoded in.

It's just simple tables, not sure what to call them.

```
string[] suggestions = new string[] { };
```

I want to add the textBox1.Text value to that table when a button is clicked.

(suggestions.add, couldn't find anything, the same with suggestions.insert)

Comment: You'll need to add a lot more detail here. Are you referring to a SQL table? How are you interacting with the table (ADO.NET, Linq to SQL, Entity Framework etc?)

Comment: It's just simple tables, not sure what to call them.
string[] suggestions = new string[]
            {
            };
I want to add the textBox1.Text value to that table when a button is clicked.

Comment: Database tables, VS DataSet/DataTables. asp.net tables? There are a lot of tables...

Comment: suggestions is an array, you'll probably want to use an List<string> if you want to have add & insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
suggestions.Add("Use Lists");
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have a database table stored in a database somewhere...

1. Determine what database you have.
2. Choose the Tools that you will use to communicate with the database, be it C# as the programming language and then a object relational mapping tool such as Linq 2 Sql or Entity Framework or plain ADO.NET

Assuming you are using SQL Server on your computer and that you have a database setup with a table called Answer and using C# with Linq 2 SQL as the ORM. Let's look at an example.

e.g

1. Open up Visual Studio
2. Start a new C# Console Application
3. View - Server Explorer -> Connect to a Database -> Type in the Server
   Name, localhost or your computer
   name and find the database on your
   machine given that the credentials
   are correct
4. View - Solution Explorer -> Right click on "ConsoleApplication1" and
   Click on Add New Item -> Data ->
   Linq to Sql Classes
5. Drag your Tables from your Server Explorer to the Design surface. You
   should now see your tables in your
   white space
6. Some code to access your table is as follows

   DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    Answer answer = new Answer();
    answer.description = "Some Description";
    context.Answers.InsertOnSubmit(answer);
    context.SubmitChanges();

I hope this helps.

Comment: the question says he's using arrays, not a table in a database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not my question. I'm assuming that you wrote this before I edited my question, I'm sorry!

Comment: I did write this before you edited your question, I do apologize for answering your question in the wrong context.

I can delete my answer, which I am happy to do

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the size of an array; arrays always have a fixed length that is specified upon their creation.

In order to add or insert values to a list of strings (a table implies more than one dimension of data, correct?) use

```
List<String> suggestions = new List<String();
suggestions.Add("Value1");
```

You can also insert values into a specific position in the list using

```
suggestions.Insert(position, value);
```

Side note: The List class is really just a wrapper around an array that allows the array to grow in size. A raw array, however, can not increase in size after instantiation.